# Which is faster: find in string or list?

Tags: .net

I have to load a large file into memory and I want to find a substring. Which method is faster?

// application initialization

```
string instring  = "which is faster find in string or list..."; // large string +- 150MB
List<string> inlist = new List<string>();
foreach (string word in instring) {
    inlist.Add(word);
}
```

// button click

```
if (instring.Contains("find")) {
  ...
}
```

or

```
if (inlist.Contains("find")) {
  ...
}
```

I have did some measurement in my case String search was the fastest.

```
Singel search:
Boyer-Moore search found - elapsed: 00:00:00.0025893
String search found - elapsed: 00:00:00.0026120
List search not found - elapsed: 00:00:00.0026394

Multi search:
Boyer-Moore search found - elapsed: 00:00:00.0027377
Boyer-Moore search found - elapsed: 00:00:00.0028308
Boyer-Moore search found - elapsed: 00:00:00.0029269
Boyer-Moore search found - elapsed: 00:00:00.0030234
Boyer-Moore search found - elapsed: 00:00:00.0031210

String search found - elapsed: 00:00:00.0032474
String search found - elapsed: 00:00:00.0032653
String search found - elapsed: 00:00:00.0032832
String search found - elapsed: 00:00:00.0033015
String search found - elapsed: 00:00:00.0033201


List search not found - elapsed: 00:00:00.0033629
List search not found - elapsed: 00:00:00.0033826
List search not found - elapsed: 00:00:00.0033961
List search not found - elapsed: 00:00:00.0034155
List search not found - elapsed: 00:00:00.0034345
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're testing radically different things.

For example, suppose you do indeed look for "find", and you've got a file which is:

```
If you're interested in finding the answer, make sure you know the question.
```

If you split that into a list of strings, one per word, then "find" doesn't appear - because it's only part of the word "finding". Using `string.Contains` you *will* find it, however, as it's a substring.

You should work out your desired *behaviour* first, implement it in the simplest, most elegant fashion, then measure performance. If that meets your desired performance, you're done. If not, you can then try to improve it, measuring at each point and making sure you've still got the *behaviour* you want.

Comment: I have did some measurement in my case String search was the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably better when you stream the file through a buffer and analyze it per line. In both cases you have to read the whole file but when you build a list you have to have the complete file content in memory

c# example from [microsoft msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        try 
        {
            // Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
            // The using statement also closes the StreamReader.
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt")) 
            {
                string line;
                string subString = "find this";
                // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
                // the file is reached.
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
                {
                    if ( line.Contains(substring) ) 
                    {
                         Console.WriteLine("Found string");
                         break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            // Let the user know what went wrong.
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```